# Disable orom in firmwarepasswd Catalina

Tags: ssd, terminal, firmware, macos-catalina

I recently had some trouble whilst
applying these **settings**

The `firmwarepasswd -disable-reset-capability` command returned with **error 6**.

Then I tried `firmwarepasswd -check / -mode`

I realized that **orom** is enabled and I would like to disable it.

I bought a after market SSD from china and I believe the embedded controller with the SSD has malicious code and is injecting at boot time and is injecting via **orom** at a ***ring0*** privilege which should be operating at ***ring3***.

Operating System is macOS **Catalina**
2016 MBP

Answer (score 0):

Since Catalina, macOS sandboxes all OROMs & forces them to run at ring 3. Prior to that it would not let them run at all unless the user forced them.

From [Apple Platform Security - Option ROM security in macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/security/secc80b0cd0c/web)

> In macOS 10.15, UEFI firmware was updated to contain a mechanism for
> sandboxing OROMs and for stripping privileges from them. UEFI firmware
> typically executes all code, including OROMs, at the maximum CPU
> privilege level, called ring 0, and has a single shared virtual memory
> space for all code and data. Ring 0 is the privilege level where the
> macOS kernel runs, whereas the lower privilege level, ring 3, is where
> apps run. The OROM sandbox de-privileged OROMs by making use of
> virtual memory separation like the kernel does and then making the
> OROMs run in ring 3.
>
> The sandbox further significantly restricts both the interfaces that
> the OROMs can call (much like system call filtering in kernels) and
> the type of device that an OROM can register as (much like app
> approval). The benefit of this design is that malicious OROMs can no
> longer directly write anywhere within ring 0 memory. Instead, they are
> limited to a very narrow and well-defined sandbox interface. This
> limited interface significantly reduces attack surface and forces
> attackers to first escape the sandbox and escalate privilege.

What isn't clear from this is whether the `firmwarepasswd` utility was changed to prevent user interaction at all, or whether this is now hard-coded. That may explain why your attempts to de-privilege failed.